# Accessing git local repository in LAN

Tags: eclipse, egit

I created java project in eclipse kepler 4.3. I created local repository of project using egit.Now I can commit the changes/revert and all.It works fine.How could I access my project repository in another computer connected in LAN?

Answer (score 0):

You must run git on the other computer in "server mode". There are various options to do this, all [explained in the documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server).

If you only need to read the repository, use the [git daemon](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon).

Alternatively, use `ssh` by using a URL like `user@othercomputer:/absolute/path/to/repo` ([docs](http://www.mindfuzz.net/?p=250)).